# Charts not loading inside Gridster

Tags: javascript, dashboard, dc.js, gridster

I am using gridster.js but when I use gridster my charts are not visible. Does anybody know why it's not visible? I use charts from dc.js

Comment: Do the same charts work outside gridster? If no one answers right away, someone will certainly answer if you create an example using e.g. blockbuilder.org or jsfiddle.net

Comment: No, I tried a simple example of dc.js I also copied al the files to avoid some other mistakes but I had no luck http://jsfiddle.net/ here is an example

Comment: Please try again with the link - it pointed to an empty jsfiddle.